# Richfaces extendedDatatable sort the empty row to be the last

Tags: sorting, datatable, richfaces, row

I am using richfaces extendedDataTable as an editable grid. The build-in sorting always sorts the empty row to be the first. I want to sort the empty row to be the last. How can I do that?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Items in RichFaces *extendedDataTable* are sorted by items natural sort oder. The list items you set as value of *extendedDataTable* should implement interface [*java.lang.Comparable*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). You can sort the empty row to be the last by method *public int compareTo(..)*

You can also sort *extendedDataTable* by clicking on the table headers. Add property *sortBy* to *rich:column* elements:

```
 <rich:extendedDataTable
   value="#{task.taskList}"
   var="item" 
   ..>                                      
     <rich:column 
       sortBy="#{item.name}"
       ..>
```

If you click on the column header table is sorted by *sortBy* value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I need to sort on a column (use sortBy) of an item property by natural sort order. What I want to override is the natural sort order so that empty value is always the last one regardless of sortOrder (DESCENDING or ASCENDING)

Comment: You can do that by adding a invisible sortBy field to your list item class. If row/item is empty you set sortBy to "zzz".